# Rolling up Values into Weekdays

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Basic SQL Query which looks at the SalesOrders table of our database, and shows all sales "per day" for a specific Sales Rep.

```
;with date_cur_month as(
    select convert(datetime, convert(varchar(6), getdate(), 112) + '01', 112) as dt
    union all
    select dateadd(day, 1, dt) as dt
    from date_cur_month
    where datepart(month, dateadd(day, 1, dt)) = datepart(month, getdate())
)
select 
    convert(nvarchar(8), d.dt, 3) as date, 
    sum(sum(ci.C_PRETAXTOTAL)) OVER (Order by CAST(d.dt AS date)) AS RunningTotal
from 
    [T_SALESORDER] ci 
right outer join date_cur_month d on 
    cast(ci.C_DATE as date) = d.dt
where 
    C_SALESREP = '8602832427308'
group by 
    d.dt
```

This works fine.

However, what I need it do is to look at the days of the week being returned, and if the day is a Saturday or Sunday, roll that data into the next working day (Mon-Fri).

So, if for example the data returned was :

```
date        RunningTotal
01/04/23    123
03/04/23    256
04/04/23    192
05/04/23    168
06/04/23      5
```

Because the 1st is a Saturday, the Monday Data (3rd April) should return £379 (123 + 256).

I have tried a few variations, but can't seem to make this work correctly.

Comment: That query won't work in SQL Server 2008, windowing like that was added in 2012.

Comment: Why do you use a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` to `date_cur_month`? You mandate that `C_SALESREP` (which can only be from `T_SALESORDER`) have a non-`NULL` value so you have an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: FWIW Sql server 2008 has not been supported since 2019: ref https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/end-of-support/sql-server-end-of-support-overview?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to simply add a custom column for ReportingDay and then aggregate by that in a subsequent step.

```
with date_cur_month as(
select convert(datetime, convert(varchar(6), getdate(), 112) + '01', 112) as dt
union all
select dateadd(day, 1, dt) as dt
  from date_cur_month
  where datepart(month, dateadd(day, 1, dt)) = datepart(month, getdate())
),
prior_result AS ( 
select convert(nvarchar(8), d.dt, 3) as date
     , sum(sum(ci.C_PRETAXTOTAL)) OVER (Order by CAST(d.dt AS date)) AS RunningTotal
  from [T_SALESORDER] ci 
    right outer join date_cur_month d on cast(ci.C_DATE as date) = d.dt
  where C_SALESREP = '8602832427308'
  group by d.dt
)
select 
CASE 
  WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, date) IN('Saturday','Sunday') 
  THEN 'Monday' 
  ELSE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, date) 
END AS ReportingDay, SUM(RunningTotal) AS SUM_RunningTotal
FROM prior_result
GROUP BY 
CASE 
  WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, date) IN('Saturday','Sunday') 
  THEN 'Monday' 
  ELSE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, date) 
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Josh.  When I run that, I get "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near 'prior_result'."  It would be "nicer" if this could be rolled up though?

Comment: I probably forgot a comma before prior_result.  Basically we have WITH date_cur_month as ( ), prior_result AS ( ) ...then the new select query which will roll it up

Comment: Sorry Josh, I added the comma to the beginning of the first prior, but now get "Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Sunday' to data type int."

Comment: Sorry @JamesDavis, I don't have SQL Server 2008 to test, but it is something to do w/ your expression that makes "date" -  it seems it is not in fact a date type, but if you can modify that to actually be a date type... perhaps CAST( AS DATE) then this will work I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a second date column (i call it dtWeekend) that you use for grouping only, something like this:

```sql
;WITH date_cur_month AS(
    SELECT  dt
    ,   dateadd(day, case (datepart(weekday, dt) + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7 + 1 when 6 then 2 when 7 then 1 else 0 end, dt) AS dtWeekend
    FROM    (
        SELECT  CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(6), getdate(), 112) + '01', 112) AS dt
        ) x
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  dateadd(day, 1, dt) AS dt
    ,   dateadd(day, 1 + case (datepart(weekday, dt) + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7 + 1  when 6 then 2 when 7 then 1 else 0 end, dt) AS dtWeekend
    FROM    date_cur_month
    WHERE   datepart(month, dateadd(day, 1, dt)) = datepart(month, getdate())
)
    SELECT  CONVERT(nvarchar(8), d.dtWeekend, 3) AS date
    ,   sum(sum(ci.C_PRETAXTOTAL)) OVER (ORDER BY CAST(d.dt AS date)) AS RunningTotal
    FROM    [T_SALESORDER] ci 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN date_cur_month d ON    cast(ci.C_DATE AS date) = d.dt
    WHERE   C_SALESREP = '8602832427308'
    GROUP BY CONVERT(nvarchar(8), d.dtWeekend, 3)
```

dtWeekend is shifted 0, 1 or 2 days from regular date depending on if it's weekday, saturday or sunday.

To avoid unpredictable server language and date settings, i'm using the @@datefirst formula

Comment: Thanks siggemannen, that's really close......only problem I have is that I'm still getting the results from the 1st (for example), as well as duplicates for Monday 4th f or example.  So, I get 1 x result for 1st, 2 for the 4th, 1 for the 5th, etc.,etc.

Comment: ok, now maybe. i forgot to change getdate() to dt  in one place :/

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the approach is you could perform another roll up on top of your first RunningTotal result by utilizing the identity trick.

Please note here I am using the US `DATE` format.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST
(
  [DATE] DATE PRIMARY KEY,
  RunningTotal INT,
  sCount INT IDENTITY(1,1)
)

INSERT INTO #TEST 
VALUES
('20230401',123),
('20230403',256),   
('20230404',192),
('20230405',168),
('20230406',5)

SELECT [DATE],
       RunningTotal as Old_RunningTotal,
       SUM(RunningTotal)OVER(
                                ORDER BY  CASE WHEN(DATEPART(DW,[DATE]) = 7) THEN DATEADD(DD,2,[DATE]) --Saturday, add 2 days
                                               WHEN(DATEPART(DW,[DATE]) = 1) THEN DATEADD(DD,1,[DATE]) --Sunday, add 1 day
                                          ELSE [DATE]
                                          END, sCount
                              ) as New_RunningTotal
FROM #TEST
ORDER BY [DATE]
```

For combining to your query, could you try:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST
(
          [DATE] DATE PRIMARY KEY,
          RunningTotal INT,
          sCount INT IDENTITY(1,1)
)

;with date_cur_month as(
select convert(datetime, convert(varchar(6), getdate(), 112) + '01', 112) as dt
union all
select dateadd(day, 1, dt) as dt
  from date_cur_month
  where datepart(month, dateadd(day, 1, dt)) = datepart(month, getdate()))

INSERT INTO #TEST
select convert(nvarchar(8), d.dt, 3) as date
     , sum(sum(ci.C_PRETAXTOTAL)) OVER (Order by CAST(d.dt AS date)) AS RunningTotal
  from [T_SALESORDER] ci 
    right outer join date_cur_month d on cast(ci.C_DATE as date) = d.dt
  where C_SALESREP = '8602832427308' 
  group by d.dt

SELECT * FROM 
(    
    SELECT [DATE],
                   RunningTotal as Old_RunningTotal,
                   SUM(RunningTotal)OVER(
                                            ORDER BY  CASE WHEN(DATEPART(DW,[DATE]) = 7) THEN DATEADD(DD,2,[DATE]) --Saturday, add 2 days
                                                           WHEN(DATEPART(DW,[DATE]) = 1) THEN DATEADD(DD,1,[DATE]) --Sunday, add 1 day
                                                      ELSE [DATE]
                                                      END, sCount
                                          ) as New_RunningTotal
     FROM #TEST
) as A
WHERE DATEPART(DW,[DATE]) NOT IN (1,7) --For excluding Weekend
     ORDER BY [DATE]
```

Comment: Thanks Long.  Sorry for the basic question (still new to SQL), but how would I integrate my original query into that?

Comment: Hey James. just included below the initial answer. let me know if any issue.

Comment: Thanks Long, that's great.  However, I want it to "EXCLUDE" the dates that are weekends too?  Is that easy?  The values are calculating great, just need to "ignore/exclude" the weekend dates please?  Thank you.

Comment: Yes James. You could simply add a 'WHERE DATEPART(DW,[DATE]) NOT IN (1,7)' from the last `SELECT` for only include the weekday records. I updated the answer too for your reference.

Comment: Thanks Long, but honestly, it's still pulling back the data from the1st, 8th, 15th, etc. :-(  Genuinely appreciate the help though!

Comment: hi James. Let me understand this well. you want the weekend to be excluded from the calculation or not shown from the final result?

Comment: Hi Long.  I would ideally like the Weekend date/s NOT to be shown in the results....but for the Running Totals to be summed up into the following Monday.  So instead of (for example) a Sales Order of £10 coming in on Saturday 1st, £20, coming in on Sunday 2nd and £30 coming in on Monday 3rd.  I would just like Monday 3rd to say £60 and for the Saturday/Sunday Order DATES to be excluded.  Hope that makes sense?  Thanks again.

Comment: understood. modified. Just a simple query for adding on top of the final result.

Comment: Hi Long, (I assume you modified the code under 'For combining to your query, could you try:')?  I just tried running the code, but still getting results from the 1st, etc...?